# How to append content with existing file?

Tags: python

How to append the content with the existing content in a same file? But It show now and existing content also..

Comment: Why was this tagged javascript-events?

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the code you've tried so far and that explains what specifically is not working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Files can be opened in python in 3 modes - 
1. Read
2. Write and
3. Append

Open the file in append mode and it should append to already present content of the file i.e. it will not override previous content.